# Voting to undelete says "Your delete vote has been recorded"

Tags: bug, localization, russian-stackoverflow, undelete

Seems there is something wrong with voting to undelete a question.

When I vote to **undelete** site says:

> Your **delete** vote has been recorded

I don't have enough rep on English-based SE sites, so can only provide screenshots from Stack Overflow in Russian:

> [image: un-delete]

[According to transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261744?key=b545a79174fcb1a87d8704e425118dab) Russian phrase:

> Ваш голос за удаление учтён

corresponds to original English phrase:

> Your delete vote has been recorded

Actual phrase for undelete should be:

> [Your undelete vote has been recorded](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261735?key=2493fb6073c1ebbb0e00003b37c8a535)

**Update:**

Nowadays I can vote to undelete here on MSE, and can confirm that English message is okay:

> [image]

Hence here is something wrong with translation mechanism. For some reason on ruSO (and maybe other localized sites) is used translation from “delete vote” source instead of “undelete vote”.

Comment: I can't recall having voted to undelete on any site (though I have the privilege somewhere, I think), but why do you think this is a network-wide issue, and not just only on Russian language sites? (+1, by the way)

Comment: @Shokhet as far as I know at least all localized SO sites (ru, pt, es, jp) use same code base.

Comment: That may be true (and is, as far as I know), but the message you're talking about is clearly a different message than what would show on EngSO or any other English language site. I've never seen Cyrillic characters in system messages on any SE site I've used. However, this [bug] may be more visible to the devs here than it would be on RuSO, so there's that.

Comment: @Shokhet I have an access to translations on ruSO, so I can see original English sentences which would be used if no translation present.